# error on import "The source file moving process failed" magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, import, validation

I am getting the error "The source file moving process failed." when trying to perform any type of import. I have tried catalog re-index, tried changing the file, been searching but cant find any solution. I can import other entities like advanced pricing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.4.x Media Gallery is introduced and is known to cause the issue.

Change this in your backend and hopefully the import will work again:

Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Media Gallery > Enable Old Media Gallery: Yes

Comment: I had that setting on Yes already

Answer (score 0):

For the Source file coping failed error message your can check, what is the ownership of the *var/importexport* directory in your Magento document root. This error may come if the file or directory ownership is different compared to the ownership on which you are running your Magento.

This error comes because of wrong permission and ownership.